# How to understand: All found on land is found also in the sea

Tags: talmud-bavli

It says in Chullin 127a that all found on land is found also in the sea, except  a "chuldah".  Is there is a larger list of such fish (other than the Gemara mentions)?  Any insights would be appreciated as to what is being taught here.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the question is. Are you looking for a comprehensive list of everything that lives on the land and its parallel in the sea, or are you just trying to get pshat in the Gemara?

Comment: Yes, I would be interested if such a list of fish existed.  All pertinent information about the concept would also be helpful.
Thanks

Comment: In that case, I'm not sure this question is possible to be answered. There's hundreds, maybe even thousands, of species on land. I'm not sure how anyone could compile a list of every parallel in existence.

Comment: Exactly, your title says "understand" and the body says "a list"?!

Answer (score -2):

The idea is simple and **it's called Symmetry**.

Our world is created symmetrical - there's good and bad, there's heaven and Earth, there's man and woman, there's waters and land etc. While they are not "exactly" the same, there's a resemblance with a different "vector". That provides the necessary equilibrium in the creation.

The life on Earth was divided between the sea and the land. *Theoretically* they should mimic each other and that what the Gemmorah claims.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the question. He didn’t ask for an explanation of the Gemara. He asked for a “larger list of such fish (other than the Gemara mentions)”.

Comment: @DonielF I think that this deals with the end of the answer `Any insights would be appreciated as to what is being taught here.` on a more fundamental level than just a list of fish. In fact, a list of fish would be avoiding the lesson and there are too many types of fish to list in any case.