# How to understand Chullin 127a: "All found on land is found also in the sea?"

Tags: talmud-gemara, agada-stories-legends, chulin-tractate

([saw a similar question suggested](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/72932/how-to-understand-all-found-on-land-is-found-also-in-the-sea))

How are we to understand the *gemara* from [Chullin 127a](https://www.sefaria.org/Chullin.127a.12?lang=bi&with=Rashi&lang2=en) which states:

> "כל שיש ביבשה יש בים"
>
> all that exists on land there is an equivalent animal in the sea

Does this mean that a gorilla equivalent lives in the sea? An elephant equivalent?

How can we understand this *gemara*- what attributes are needed to be considered "equivalent?"

Comment: The Gemara doesn’t say any animal - it says anything. What’s the marine equivalent to humans?

Comment: @DonielF - AquaMan and his harem of mermaids...and Mr. Limpet and Ladyfish.

Comment: @DonielF you're right- fixed

Comment: Similar duplicate of the day’s Daf: surviving on a revisis of blood